# Swift optional binding in while loop

Tags: swift

According to [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309):

> **Optional** binding can be used with **if** and **while** **statements** to check for a value inside an optional, and to extract that value into a constant or variable, as part of a single action.

The documentation only shows an example of optional-binding using if statement like:

```
if let constantName = someOptional {
    statements
}
```

I'm looking for an example of **optional-binding** using while loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the same

```
while let someValue = someOptional
{
    doSomethingThatmightAffectSomeOptional(with: someValue)
}
```

Here is a concrete example of iterating a linked list.

```
class ListNode
{
    var value: String
    var next: ListNode?

    init(_ value: String, _ tail: ListNode?)
    {
        self.value = value
        self.next = tail
    }
}

let list = ListNode("foo", ListNode("bar", nil))

var currentNode: ListNode? = list
while let thisNode = currentNode
{
    print(thisNode.value)
    currentNode = thisNode.next
}

// prints foo and then bar and then stops
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the advantage of using `while let ...` is infinite loop that check some variable for any changes. But it's weird. For this kind of work you should use `didSet`. Or other good example is `List` data structure. Anyway, here is the example:

```
var value: Int? = 2

while let value = value {
    print(value) // 2
    break
}
```